# Parsing xml namespaces using ajax

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, url, namespaces

```
<item>
<guid>http://jahboo.fliggo.com/video/kPZj01cs</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 10 Mar 2009 18:31:38 -0500</pubDate>
<title>How to be perverted with water proof cam</title>
<author>Jennisita@fliggo</author>
<link>http://jahboo.fliggo.com/video/kPZj01cs</link>
<description>
    This vid shows how easy it is to make perverted vids with a water proof cam. Kids don&apos;t try this @ home.   <![CDATA[ <object width="425" height="355"><param name="movie" value="http://jahboo.fliggo.com/embed/kPZj01cs"></param><param name="wmode" value="window"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><param name="allowfullscreen" value="yes"></param><embed src="http://jahboo.fliggo.com/embed/kPZj01cs" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="window" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="yes" width="425" height="355"></embed></object> ]]> </description>
<media:group>
    <media:title>How to be perverted with water proof cam</media:title>
    <media:content url="http://static.fliggo.com/content/k/P/16119.flv" type="video/flv" bitrate="450" fileSize="0" framerate="0" duration="29" height="400" width="300" />
    <media:player url="http://jahboo.fliggo.com/embed/kPZj01cs" height="400" width="300" />
    <media:credit role="author">Jennisita</media:credit>
    <media:thumbnail url="http://static.fliggo.com/content/k/P/16119-158-large.jpg" />
    <media:text type="plain">This vid shows how easy it is to make perverted vids with a water proof cam. Kids don&apos;t try this @ home.</media:text>  
</media:group>
```

I want to parse the following xml data. i want to retrieve data from the media:thumbnail namespace and access the url attribute within that namespace. Is there any tool or tutorial that can guide me in doing this? thank you

Comment: In which language do you want to do this?

Comment: ajax is not a language, it's a style ... javascript is the language!

Comment: I want to parse it in php. It's basically a feed from fliggo, the video sharing site. I want to display the thumbnails on my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to do this with JavaScript.

[DOM level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) has methods for dealing with namespaces, but unfortunately Internet Explorer doesn't support these.

So you are left with the following options:

1. Don't support IE.
2. Write the code ignoring namespaces using DOM level 1 methods.
3. Find JavaScript XML library that supports namespaces.
4. Develop your own JavaScript XML library.
5. Just use a regex to extract those strings.

Comment: do you have any ideas of any library that supports namespaces? Any examples of parsing the namespace using regex?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea of the libraries. About the regex: I meant just scanning XML with regex like /media:thumbnail url="(.*?)"/

Comment: don't worry I found something that got the job done perfectly thanks again

Answer (score -1):

You should **read** about this, there are [soooo many examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%2Bxml%2Bparse&btnG=Searrrch) on the web about this...

start with the basics, **[JasvaScript & XML](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/definitive2/index.html)** by David Flanagan, it covers **how to create**, **read**, **load** xml synchronous and asynchronous, and **parse** the XML data... and even **convert** XML into a html table.

Comment: The thing is i need to integrate the following feed in my site and its kinda giving me a bit of trouble. I want to customize it to my liking, anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: There are many examples, but I'd be happy to see just one that parses namespaced xml.

Comment: The question is specifically about handling namespaces in xml. The answer misses the point.